# Pivot / Transpose header table to rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
part_num | type  | color | material
_________|_______|_______|_____________
1234     | filter| white | steel
```

this table has a part number, part type, color and material.

How can I pivot / transpose the table to get output below:

```
part |AttrName| AttrValue
_____|________|__________
1234 |type    | filter
1234 |color   | white
1234 |material| steel
```

Oracle Database 12c - 12.2.2
I have not used pivot or unpivot before so an explanation would be nice to understand the difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach uses a series of unions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT part_num AS part, 'type' AS AttrName, "type" AS AttrValue FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT part_num, 'color', color FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT part_num, 'material', material FROM yourTable
)

SELECT part, AttrName, AttrValue
FROM cte
ORDER BY part;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT` in oracle 11g but if you've lower version then `UNION ALL` could be an approach

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d6d72d2c561616734baacc5a015a3503)**

```
SELECT *
    FROM t UNPIVOT (AttrValue FOR AttrName IN(
    type,color,material))
```

OUTPUT:

```
ART_NUM ATTRNAME    ATTRVALUE
1234    TYPES        filter
1234    COLOR        white
1234    MATERIAL     steel
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 12C supports lateral joins, so I would use:

```
select t.part_num, x.*
from t cross apply
     (select 'type' as AttrName, "type" as AttrValue from dual union all
      select 'color', color from dual union all
      select 'material', material from dual
     ) x;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=91ebe80a827d435de0c8295dd1a62162) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that Oracle also supports this syntax:

```
select t.part_num, x.*
from t cross join lateral
     (select 'type' as AttrName, "type" as AttrValue from dual union all
      select 'color', color from dual union all
      select 'material', material from dual
     ) x;
```